# Oracle DB - count non-consecutive actions

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have the scenario where the SQL in oracle db, should return the count of the shown variables value as below.

Action field will have Insert and Delete as a value for different time stamp but when I report the count it should be like for the given input.

[image]

The logic is all the `Insert` or all the `Delete` should be counted as `1` till it hits `delete` or `Insert` respectively.

Like a call center a customer can add any number of compliant (Insert) but that should be counted as 1 for that user id, if the already registered complaint is resolved (Delete) then next sequence of complaint (Insert) should be counted as one.

Any help is highly appreciated and Many thanks in advance!

Deva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select keyfield, action, count(*) from (
  select lead(action, 1, 'other') over (partition by keyfield order by timestamp) as naction, action from t1)
where action != naction group by action, keyfield;
```

Idea is to use analytic function to select only those records which are followed by other (ignore chains of same actions) action. Then group by action and id to do count.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.. I just wanted to be more clear idea about the data, input and expected output in SQL-oracle code. I have updated the sample input data and the expected output in the initial thread.  Could you please help me.